# Using Jupyter Notebook to plot data from rosbag files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ros

I have multiple rosbag files with a ton of data, and what I would like to do is analyze these bag files using Jupyter Notebook, but the problem is that each bag has a different set of data parameters. So I have created msg files to subscribe to data from each bag file. Some msg files have the same variables since those variables are used in multiple plots.

Can someone walk me through the process of getting the plots on the notebook file one at a time (from the data obtained from the bag files), for every bag file I have? Even if multiple files use the same topics?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you ask. Do you want to plot each rosbag content seperatly or combine their content? Where are you encountering an issue? Post some code of your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer in one of the older *.ipynb* files. Plots can be obtained with Plotly library.  It really doesn't matter how many bag files are being scanned for topics and are plotted. Each bag file can be separately converted using the 'bag_to_dataframe' function from the "rosbag_pandas" package.

Even in case of similar topics between bag files, it is possible to differentiate their values in the plots. Hope this helps, I'll share a sample bag file soon :)